# Sort an simple linked list

Tags: java, list

I try to sort an linked list, but my code didn't work and idk why.

My input: 85, 92, 78, 27, 13, 68, 11, 92, 73

My output before using sort method: 85, 78, 92, 27, 13, 68, 11, 92, 73.

```
  Node prev = first;
  Node aux = first.next;
  Node next = aux.next;
  while (next != null) {
                if (Utility.greaterT(aux.data, next.data)) {
                    aux.next = next.next;
                    prev.next = next;
                    next.next = aux;
                    
                    prev = next;
                    next = aux.next;
                    aux = aux.next;
                } else {
                    prev = aux;
                    aux = next.next;
                    next = next.next;
                } // If
            } // While;
```

the method greaterT just verifiy if the first value is bigger than the second value.

Just sorting the second and the third value.

Comment: Try to use a debugger to see step by step what the code is doing and where it deviates from your expectations.

Comment: It would also be worthwhile looking up "bubble sort" to understand how a simple sort algorithm works.  Note that you cannot do it in a single pass through your list ... as your code is trying to do.

Comment: @Henry the method never goes in to the if, only the first time that i run it

Comment: then @StephenC what do you propose?

Comment: What I propose is that you lookup bubblesort!!  For example, in Wikipedia.  Read it.  Understand it.  Then apply the ideas to your linked list sorting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is your algorithm cannot be fixed. Please take Sephen's advise to learn about a possible solution: e.g. [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (the article exists in different languages if that helps)

I'll try to explain and hope you will see better then.

You are trying to sort a singly linked list and you are using 3 references (`prev`, `aux` and `next`). You cannot sort an arbitrary singly linked list with this approach. To see this try to think about the following:

At any given moment you can compare at most 4 values: `prev`, `aux`, `next` and `next.next` - that is what you can do at the moment (if you think of using `var.next.next...`, that won't work in general).

Let's presume that is what you will do and you start with the first 4 items. Assume you can sort them correctly in order, e.g. `4 5 6 7 ...`

You move on with the 3 references and you see something like: `5 6 7 3` - what is going to be done with the first item `4` ? It is obviously greater than `3` - you will end up with `4 3 5 6 7 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your chunk of code with this

```
  Node prev = first;
  Node aux = first.next;
  Node next = aux.next;
  while (next != null) {
                if (Utility.greaterT(aux.data, next.data)) {
                    aux.next = next.next;
                    prev.next = next;
                    next.next = aux;
                    
                    prev = next;
                    next = aux.next;
                    // I eliminated this line
                } else {
                    prev = aux;
                    aux = next;
                    next = next.next;
                } // If
            } // While;
```

Comment: You spot that part correctly. However, the questioner's issues are beyond that point. The first element 85 remains in place for example.

Comment: It work's but the first element remains in the first position.